# Dracut Emerg Shell: Mount LVM2 volume

Tags: linux, fedora, lvm, fstab, dracut

How can I mount a (LUKS encrypted) LVM volume in the dracut emergency shell?

I made fatal changes to /etc/fstab that needs to be undone.

I did `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/mmcblk0p2 crypthome` and entered the passphrase.

Then tried to mount:
`mount /dev/mapper/crypthome /mnt/crypthome`

but got this error message:

`mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'`

Isn't it possible to mount a LVM partition in dracut?

Answer (score 0):

You do not mount "LVM Partition" as you call it - that's a physical volume (PV). LVM is all about using "logical volumes" (LVs) backed by PVs.

1. You should see if LV is present and active (`lvs`).
   1.1 If it is not present, you should run `pvscan --cache /dev/mapper/crypthome`. And go to one.
   1.2 If it is not active, run `lvchange -ay $VG/$LV`
2. Mount the LV: `mount /dev/$VG/$LV`